# MinGW32 remapping network drive (sh.exe": cd: /x/: No such file or directory

Tags: git, bash, mingw, mingw32

I use git bash on MinGW32. I have a remote repository on X:.

Sometimes windows looses the connection to X:\

Not a problem for windows, I just double click on the icon for X:\ in Windows Explorer and it asks me for my windows username and my password and hey presto I am reconnected.

However once this connection has been lost from the git bash window (which I assume could be any MinGW bash window) I can no longer access x:\

$ cd /x/ returns:
    sh.exe": cd; /x/: No such file or directory.

The only way I have found to recover from this is to reboot the PC.
I am using Windows 8 pro 32 bit if this is relevant

Is there a way to access /x/ from mingw32 bash without rebooting.

Comment: Try `cd $PWD` after the connection is re-established & you have entered password.

Comment: yes that is it duh. I thought I had tried that but I guess I must have had another bash window open. Thanks

Comment: Adding as answer, so that you can close the question...

Comment: btw, didn't the other solution help?

Answer (score 2):

Just restart your `bash` sessions.